# using past perfect in a 'by the time' clause instead of simple past

Tags: simple-past-vs-past-perfect

How would using past perfect in a 'by the time' clause affect the meaning differently from using the common formula (past simple in the 'by the time clause' plus past perfect in the main clause). For example, what could the following mean?

> By the time he had finished dinner, it was time for bed.

Comment: I don't think "By the time he finished dinner, it had been time for bed" fits any "common formula". In fact, it seems to be missing something crucial to its meaning. Are you asking why?

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is used to talk about the order of events in the past.  Your sentence means that in the past, he finished dinner and that when he finished dinner it was time for bed.  Maybe it took him 3 hours to eat dinner and he finished at 11pm.  The fist event is eating dinner, the second is bed time.

If you say "by the time he finished dinner it was time for bed," the idea of past order isn't really there as much.

The difference in meaning is minuscule.  Using "by the time" just introduces another time phrase in the sentence. You could just as well say "when he..."

Comment: When you say "The fi[r]st event is eating dinner, the second is bed time", it looks almost as though you think the sentence means that bed time only came after finishing dinner. _By_ of course means "at or before", which is the opposite of "after".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I didn't know that what I've always called "pluperfect" is now usually called "past perfect", so thank you for highlighting that for me.

My understanding of the question is that you are examining the difference between these two sentences:

1. "By the time he had finished dinner, it was time for bed."
2. "By the time he finished dinner, it was time for bed."

I would say that there is very little difference between the two.  I would infer a little more finality from the first one, in that dinner was definitely over and done with, and that he had left the table.  The second would suggest to me that he had just finished eating.  Hence, I would say that the past perfect version implies more completeness to the activity than the second.  But as I said, the difference feels minuscule to me.

It's an interesting question though and, like WS2, I'd be interested to read other people's take on this.

Comment: You are not the only one who thinks of the so-called "past-perfect" as "the pluperfect"!

Comment: I read somewhere that pluperfect, perfect, and perfective all mean different things, but in English I still feel safe using "past perfect" for the "had" + past.participle verb form.

Comment: _By_ means "at or before", so the sentence being asked about does not mean that bedtime came _after_ he left the table but just the opposite. Either he was still eating when bedtime came, or bedtime came, at the latest, at the very moment he finished.

Answer (score 0):

"It had been time for bed" needs some help from adverbials:

(S1) "By the time he finished dinner, it had already been time for bed for quite a while."

This sentence (S1) means that bed time definitely started before he finished dinner.

But the original sentence uses "was" to allow for the possibility that the finishing of dinner was simultaneous with bedtime:

(S2) "By the time he finished dinner, it was (already) time for bed."

There are two possibilities inherent in the word "by": (a) before, and (b) at the same time. For example, "by 3 o'clock" means "either before 3 o'clock or at 3 o'clock", or in other words "no later than 3 o'clock".

"By" has the same meaning in sentence S2, which says that it became time for bed either before he finished dinner or at the very moment he finished dinner. S2 clearly means that he did **not** finish dinner **before** it became time for bed.

Adding "had" gives us the original sentence:

(S3) "By the time he had finished dinner, it was time for bed."

This does not change the meaning of "by" and does not change the two inherent possibilities. Sentence S3 still means that he had **not** finished dinner **before** it became time for bed.

Changing "finished" to "had finished" in a "by the time" clause does not invert the meaning of "by" or make the sentence mean that finishing dinner came before time for bed.

Notice that "he **did** not finish dinner before bedtime" and "he **had** not finished dinner before bedtime" also exclude the same possibility.

Conclusion: Past perfect does **not** automatically change the order of events. We use past perfect to express either that one event happened before another or that one event did **not** happen before another.

One more example:

(S4) "He was caught before he had run half a mile."

This means that he did **not** run half a mile before he was caught. In fact, the use of "had run" in S4 suggests that, because he was caught, he **never** completed that half-mile run.

Answer (score -2):

S4 above, is not correct. The sentence is:

He had been caught before he ran half a mile. (He'd been caught...)

Two points:

1. using the past perfect in the first clause shows his being caught happened before he ran the mile.
2. "before" begins a time clause that takes the simple past form of the verb. This sentence sequence shows that he was caught before he finished runningthe mile.

Comment: Backshifting *was* to *had been* changes the timeframe completely. S4 is entirely idiomatic and correct.